# Highcharts gantt chart task progress indicator data labels for multi-color in a single task progress

Tags: highcharts

Please refer the image. I need to show datalabels name over on each color of the progress.

[image]

```
  var markers = JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString("uspTaskProgress1","",null,1,10) %>');
            var colors = ['skyblue', 'orange', 'red','blue'];
            var statusprogress = ['Overall Subtask Percentage'];
            var Arrayset = [];
            var starts1 = [];
            var ends1 = [];
            var val1 = [];
            var val2 = [];
            var categories = [];

            if (markers != null) {
                if (markers.length > 0) {
                    var prj=document.getElementById("param1").value;
                    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

                        var syearval = parseInt(markers[i].ActualStart.substr(0, 4));
                        var smonthval = parseInt(markers[i].ActualStart.substr(5, 2))-1;
                        var sdateval = parseInt(markers[i].ActualStart.substr(8, 2));

                        var eyearval = parseInt(markers[i].ActualEnd.substr(0, 4));
                        var emonthval = parseInt(markers[i].ActualEnd.substr(5, 2))-1;
                        var edateval = parseInt(markers[i].ActualEnd.substr(8, 2));
                        val1 = [Date.UTC(syearval, smonthval, sdateval)];
                        val2 = [Date.UTC(eyearval, emonthval, edateval)];
                        starts1.push(val1[0]);
                        ends1.push(val2[0]);

                        Arrayset.push({ color:colors[i],name: markers[i].Task, start: starts1[i], end: ends1[i], completed: markers[i].OverallSubtaskPercentage, y:0});
                    }
                    for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
                        categories.push(markers[j].Task);
                    }


                     MainLoadChart(Arrayset, categories);

                }
            }
```

```
 function MainLoadChart(array,categories) {
                var dta = array;

                Highcharts.ganttChart('container8', {

                    chart: {
                        type: 'xrange'
                    },

                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime'
                    },
                    yAxis: {

                        categories: categories,
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: 'Task Progress Indicator Status'
                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        formatter() {

                            let output = ` <span style="font-size: 20px;color:green">${prj}</span><br>
                                      <span><b>${this.key}(Overall Subtask Percentage):${this.point.completed}% </b></span><br>
                                     <span>Start: ${Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %e. %b, %Y', this.x)}</span><br>
                     <span>End: ${Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %e. %b, %Y', this.x2)}</span>`
                            return output
                        }
                    },

                    series: [{

                        data:dta,

                        dataLabels: {
                            formatter() {

                                let output1 = ` <span style="font-size: 10px">${this.point.completed}%</span>`
                                return output1
                            }
                        }


                        }]

                      });
            }
```

I added datalabels property in series.data but it's not showing in the output. Can let us know how to add the data labels name on each color of the task progress. Image attached. It's a highcharts gantt chart.Code is attached please have a review on the code

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **dataLabels** options, like formatter to set what data label should display, for each point in the data config.

Like this:

```
    data: [{
        name: 'test1',
        start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 18),
        end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 25),
        completed: 0.25,
        y: 0,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
          x: 150,
          formatter() {
            return 'test1'
          }
        }
    }, ...]
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/am0w5Lkr/

In the above demo I set the x to some fixed value because I am not sure if your chart should be responsive or not. In case of the responsive chart, I encourage to use the **render** callback https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render to calculate datalabels position after each resizes.

---

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.x

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.formatter

Comment: Hi, how to set dynamically. Please check the code which is attached. Thanks

Comment: Here is an example of how to positioning the dataLabels dynamically: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gxauhL14/